# place another widgets with TabBarView

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a TabBar as a bottom of my appbar like this:

```
appBar: new AppBar(
            bottom:
                TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  indicatorColor: Color(0xff2CB57D),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: uiLabels['tab1'][globals.currentLang],
                ),
                Tab(text: uiLabels['tab2'][globals.currentLang]),
              ],
            ),
```

And then in the body like this:

```
 body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              PollsListPage(),
              PollsListPage(),
            ],
          ),
```

This is working just fine .. the problem is that i want to add Positioned widget in the body with the TabBarView ..

How can i do this?

Comment: could you please a bit more precise and detail what you actually want to achieve, so that we can better help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that i can put a body widget which is for both and then customize it as  i need ..